# Creating a search box similar to facebook

Tags: php, ajax

I want to create a search box for my website where results are show as I am typing. The idea is that as people type something in, the user table will be searched for that username.

".TBL_USERS." is the table. 
The row would be username.

How would I go about doing this?

THankyou

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery UI [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) widget, it should be what you want.